# Global variable and local variable in Python classes

Tags: python, class

```
x = "xtop"
y = "ytop"
def func():
    x = "xlocal"
    y = "ylocal"
    class C:
        print x  #xlocal  of course
        print y  #ytop  why? I guess output may be 'ylocal' or '1'
        y = 1
        print y  #1  of course
func()
```

1. Why x and y are different here？
2. If I replace `class C` with a function scope I will get `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'y' referenced before assignment`，What is the difference between a class and a function in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this is because the scope of `class C` is actually different than the scope of `def func` - and the different defaulting behaviors of scopes that python has for resolving names.

Here is basically how python looks for a variable in a step-by-step guide:

- Look in current scope
- If current scope doesn't have it → use nearest enclosing scope
- If current scope has it, but not yet defined → use global scope
- If current scope has it, and already defined → use it
- Otherwise we blow up

(If you remove `ytop` you get the exception `NameError: name 'y' is not defined`)

So basically, when the interpreter looks at the following section of code it does this

```
class C:
    print(x) # need x, current scope no  x → default to nearest (xlocal)
    print(y) # need y, current scope yes y → default to global  (ytop)
             #         but not yet defined 
    y = 1
    print(y) # okay we have local now, switch from global to local scope
```

Consider the following scenarios and the different outputs we would get in each case

```
1) class C:
    print(x)
    print(y)

>>> xlocal
>>> ylocal

2) class C:
    y = 1
    print(x)
    print(y)  

>>> xlocal
>>> 1

3) class C:
    print(x)
    print(y)
    x = 1
 
>>> xtop
>>> ylocal
```

Comment: Why will we get an output, no object of `class C` is created?

Comment: @ShashankSingh In python, all `class` objects are evaluated immediately. `def` objects (functions) are not.

Comment: If I replace `class C` with  `def C():` function  and call it after its definition I get `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'y' referenced before assignment`，What is the difference between a class and a function in this situation?

Comment: @ShashankSingh That is a rather complex question. It has to do with how python interprets the code. You will need to read https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: The point you wrote under `Here is basically how python looks for a variable` applies to classes only and not function, right?

Comment: @ShashankSingh They apply to both. You are confusing scoping and the interpretation flow between functions and classes.